# Сложная фильтрация товаров по свойствам - PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

Cтолкнулся с некоторой сложностью и хотел бы получить совета от более опытных коллег.

Есть 3 таблицы: product, attributes, rships. В первой хранятся товары, а во второй свойства этих товаров (вес, цвет и т.д.), а в третьей связь между первыми двумя таблицами по id.

На странице каталога есть фильтр этих самых свойств. Т.е. посетитель сайта может выделить чекбоксом любой фильтр и данные подгружаются.

Я делаю динамический запрос (Т.е. берутся данные id из каждого чекбокса и делается новый RIGHT JOIN, снизу пример с 2 свойствами):

```
SELECT
    product.id,
    product.title,
    product.img
FROM
    product
RIGHT JOIN rships t1 ON
    t1.id_attr IN ('2') AND product.id = t1.id_post
RIGHT JOIN rships t2 ON
    t2.id_attr IN('37') AND product.id = t2.id_post
GROUP BY
    product.id
```

Вопрос такой: когда пользователь выбирает, например, не 2 свойства, а 10, то уже подключается 10 RIGHT JOIN. Насколько это критично для нагрузки на базу? Ведь подключаем 10 одинаковых таблиц. И можно ли как-то оптимизировать данный запрос, избежать столько join'ов? 
Спасибо!

Comment: А что прям 1 таблицей не обойтись? Покажите нагляднее, что вы там делаете, а то ничего не понятно, о каких фильтрах и аттрибутах идет речь.

Comment: 1 таблицей не обойтись, т.к. таблица attributes это все свойства. Их можно отдельно создавать, редактировать, удалять, добавлять любым товарам или убирать. Речь идет об интернет магазине и фильтрации товаров с помощью фильтра на сайте.

Comment: Очень жаль, что у вас там все так гибло реализовано.

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает сделать так?

```
SELECT
    product.id,
    product.title,
    product.img
FROM
    product
RIGHT JOIN rships t1 ON
    t1.id_attr IN ('2', '37') AND product.id = t1.id_post
GROUP BY
    product.id
```

Comment: Просто оператор IN в данном случае сделает условие ИЛИ, а мне нужно И.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вот так

SELECT
    product.id,
    product.title,
    product.img
FROM
    product
RIGHT JOIN rships t1 ON
    (t1.id_attr=2 AND product.id = t1.id_post) or (t1.id_attr=37 AND product.id = t1.id_post)
GROUP BY
    product.id

Comment: Так это тоже самое, что и IN в вашем прошлом примере. Выводит точно такие же результаты.

Comment: SELECT product.id, product.title, product.img FROM product RIGHT JOIN rships t1 ON t1.id_attr=2 AND t1.id_attr=37 AND product.id = t1.id_post   GROUP BY product.id